# Gridview OnRowDeleting event won't fire when EnableEventValidation = false

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using a gridview, there is no problem binding it and filling it with data from code-behind. But now I want to use the OnRowDeleting event so that I'm able to delete a row from my gridview.

When I press the delete button I got this error:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

So I added EnableEventValidation = false, then when I pressed the delete button nothing happend at all. The event wasn't fired (checked with a breakpoint at GridView1_RowDeleting).

How can I make the event fire without any problems?

My gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="gridviewGridlinesSkin"
    OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
    EmptyDataText="No positions found" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDatabound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit" 
                    CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_edit.gif" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" 
                    CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_delete.gif" 
                    OnClientClick='<%# Eval("strPositionName", "return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this entry {0}?\");") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    //Some controls here
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //Make delete with the values from the row but event won't fire
}
```

Comment: Try debugging it and what happens is that a postback is made and then nothing more...

Comment: use rowcommand event in place of rowdeleting

Comment: And how do I check there if the user typed "delete"?